# python eliminating leading zeros in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have a function foo(): that take bytes, concatenates them and returns the int value. however when i pass foo('99', '00'), the leading 0 of a byte will get trimmed. resulting in string '990' instead of '9900'.

```
def foo(value1, value2):
    return int(value1+value2, 16)
```

I was wondering if there was a graceful way of telling python that the I want the parameters to be treated as a string instead of ints. I am able to do a workaround (shown below) to make sure there are two digits to each parameter. Just wondering if there is another way to go about this

```
def foo(value1,value2):
    if(len(str(value1)) != 2):
        value1 = "0"+str(value1)
    if(len(str(value2)) != 2):
        value2 = "0"+str(value2)
    return int(str(value1)+str(value2), 16)
```

Edit: foo(99,00), not foo('99','00') is what is giving me the issues I am dealing with

Comment: `foo('99', '00')` returns 39168 - I really don't get you

Comment: 39168 *is* the right value converting 9900 from hex to decimal by the way.  I don't see where the 0 is getting trimmed.

Comment: @chrisz yep. it uses "9900" as base 16 - converts to int - so this question does not really makes sense to me

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) please debug the inputs to foo

Comment: `int('990', 16) = 2448` while `int('9900', 16) = 39168` (the same result is for `foo('99', '00')`). Everything seems fine.

Comment: Why making sure that each argument is a 2-character string? If the two arguments form a valid input for base-16 conversion everything is fine, if not, there will be an exception. Why ask for permission? Or do you have data-sanitation requirements for this function?

Comment: @PatrickArtner  sorry, I edited my question, foo(99,00) is what is giving me the issues.

Comment: Oh my... You are passing integers to foo (and they will be base 10), and are treating them like a base16 representation of some value.

Comment: @chrisz I edited my question, it was foo(99,00) not foo('99','00') giving me the problem.

Comment: @chrisz that wont work. python will treat 00 as just 0

Comment: because str(00) = 0. But `int(str(value1).zfill(2) + str(value2).zfill(0), 16)` will

Comment: Ah good point.  Then use @Scott Hunter's answer when you pass in the arguments.

Comment: You can go with `int("{:02d}{:02d}".format(value1, value2), 16)`, but that won't solve the fact that your inputs cannot express base 16.

Comment: @Faibbus yeah I was hoping there was a way to define the type, sorta like foo(str value1, str value2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"%02d" % n` will yield a string with the decimal representation of the integer in `n` of at least 2 characters w/ leading 0's .

Comment: What has this to do with the question? You think the error is when converting a 0 byte to the inputs of foo() ? Q would make much more sense that way...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right answer. You'll just need to convert your inputs into strings first. I believe you may also want to make the inputs dynamic, so you can change it up to use that.

```
def foo(*args):
  return int(''.join(map(lambda x: str(x).zfill(2), args)), 16)

print foo('90', '01')       # 36865
print foo('00', 'FF')       # 255
print foo('01', '00')       # 256
print foo('00', '01', '50') # 336
print foo('0', '1', '0')    # 256 - same as foo('00', '01', '00')
```

or if you want to accept Hex strings of any length

```
def foo(*args):
  return int(''.join(map(lambda x: str(x).zfill((len(str(x)) + 1) / 2 * 2), args)), 16)

print foo('0001', '01')     # 257
print foo('001', '1')       # 257 - same as foo('0001', '01')
```

Basically the addition rounds the length of each element to the nearest even number of characters before joining them together.

***Edit***: Here's the updated code with respect to entering whole number, and the second version even allows numbers above 255.

Comment: While the code is fine, this really seems to be creating a problem that has not been asked in the question.